# Is bribery damaging to society?

Tags: economics

Many commentators in the developed countries insist that bribery is a form of corruption and needs to be stamped out in developing countries, contending that it is bad for the people.

The main argument is that increases the gap between the rich and the poor.

Does bribery have more negative effects on a developing nation than positive effects, if any?

Comment: Not a real question, but an attempt to start a discussion, which is inappropriate in this forum.

Comment: I can answer this, but I have other things to tend to.  It may be that a sudden, inexplicable increase in my reputation would change my priorities...

Comment: @Adam - Here is a promissory note for 10x sock puppet votes once the answer is forth coming.

Comment: Of course it has negative effects. What a question. Instead of upholding the law, police see through fingers with crime because they are bribed. Good or bad for society? Instead of giving the goverment contract to the best offer, it goes to somebodies incompetent nephew. Good or bad for society? Geez.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: "My country" is badly defined. In Poland there is a lot of this going on, yes. In Sweden, where I came from originally, contracts do not go to incompetent nephews, no. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_Perceptions_Index

Comment: @Lennart - I realised too late this question lends itself better to a discussion and doesn't belong here (thus my own vote to close). Your comment is just an insult and taken out of context from my original posting. If you don't like my question vote to close. But there's no need to be a jerk about it.

Comment: Fail for lacking the wit to include a bounty along with this question.

Comment: I like the question but really bribery does a great deal of good for those societies that are doing it, and does damage to the societies who are ruled by the former.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes it does. Source: any textbook on game theory or economics.

Bribery changes the payoff of the game.

Here's a simple model.

Say an official needs to decide 1000 things. In 100 of them the payoff function is skewed by things like currying political favor/nepotism.

The payoff function for the other 900 is "How will those decisions affect my job performance". Imperfectly, the job performance somewhat correlates with how good those decisions were. E.g. if you're in charge of building a factory, your decisions affect how cheap and fast it is built. Your bosses would reward you (presumably, all other things being equal) for faster/cheaper result. So you will make decisions which achieve that result, thus enhancing productivity. This is good for your country.

Now, say you HAVE bribery. On 600 of those 900 decisions, your payoff function suddenly becomes different - if the amount of bribe exceeds the extra benefits to you from doing the job well on that decision, you will make a less productive decision to get the bribe.

This decreases productivity.

---

An additional problem is that bribery imposes extra costs (and thus hampers economic output), especially on smaller firms.

Source: http://rru.worldbank.org/documents/publicpolicyjournal/074ackerm.pdf

Comment: This seems to assume bribery is instigated by a mysterious outside force with money that they printed in their own yard. Remember that bribes come from somewhere, for some purpose. Although illegitimate, bribery is still a form of trade. Obviously the briber is trying to effect an advantageous decision from the bribee (advantageous to the briber), but this is the same (in essence) as the boss in this example. The boss wants the worker to do a good job so incentivizes him/her with potential raise, the briber wants the worker to do X to uses a bribe instead. I am curious what effects this has.

Comment: Basically my point is: is it proven that listening to your boss is better for society than listening to your average briber? Of course bribers aren't very altruistic, but neither are peoples bosses. Both are driven by capitalistic goals, whether they are going through legally sanctioned means or not shouldn't play a part should it?

(I'm not attacking your answer, just being skeptical. After all this is skeptics exchange ;) )

Comment: @Razor - simple. With some rare exceptions of an enlightened briber and really incompetent/evil boss, if what the briber wanted the outcome to be would be beneficial, the boss would want the same and the bribe would not be needed.

Comment: Ok cool, make sense :)

Comment: Cool source, though it would be nice to see how what you gathered from the source actually informs your answer (quotes, or inline references?)

Comment: The conclusion in your answer might be correct, but the argument made I don't think is complete enough. Your argument looks at a kind of "local" game, then adds bribery as an available move in this game, but doesn't consider the fact that a bribery move has external effects (part of another game, or really, part of a a "global" game). Also I think care is needed in the definition of bribery, so that it is not confused with "corruption", and so it's clear whether referring to bribery under the law or not (which has further implications).

Comment: @Razor Storm It's important to note that bribery is NOT a form of trade. Bribery happens when someone takes money for something that is not theirs. If someone promises to give me money for spending my money with them, that's a price reduction. If they give me money for spending someone else's money with them, that's bribery.

Comment: @DJClayworth, isn't bribery simply paying for an illegal service? For instance, paying politicians to make a decision, or paying a coast guard to look the other way when you are smuggling. It doesn't always have to do with spending other people's money does it? To the most benign it could be paying your boss to allow you to harass your workers.

Answer (score 17):

In a paper by Jennifer Hunt and Sonia Laszlo, from McGill University, [Bribery: Who Pays, Who Refuses, What Are The Payoﬀs?](http://www.econ.berkeley.edu/users/webfac/qian/e261_s06/jennyhunt1.pdf), the authors cite work of Shleifer and Vishny that

> ...suggest[s] that bribery of public
>   oﬃcials has economic eﬀects that can
>   prove more distortionary than
>   taxation.

In their study's introduction, the authors continue to cite supporting evidence of bribery being detrimental to a country's development:

> Mauro (1995) ﬁnds cross–country evidence that corruption reduces
>   economic growth. Moreover, many development economists fear that corruption reduces
>   equity as well as eﬃciency, constituting a regressive tax, causing the poor to be excluded
>   from public services, and skewing growth in favor of the rich.

For their case study of Peru, the authors conclude that

> Compared with a client dealing with an oﬃcial acting scrupulously, a client who pays
>   a bribe reluctantly has a slightly lower probability of concluding her business with the
>   oﬃcial, a client who pays a bribe voluntarily has a similar probability, while a client who
>   refuses to bribe has a much lower probability (by 16 percentage points)

therefore, bribery actually delays resolution of official matters instead of facilitating it, with a significant impact on those who refuse to pay or cannot afford it.

Comment: What does “more distortionary than taxation” mean? This seems like a very odd comparison to make, unless the agenda was to make taxes look bad.

Answer (score 3):

While I like DVK's answer, let's add another one that is I hope simpler.

An official has to decide which contractor to use to build a bridge. In the absence of bribery they will choose the bid that gets the best value, to the best of their ability. All well and good. With bribery in the picture the contract will go to a contractor with a higher price, or lower quality, costing the bridge builder (usually a government) more money. The actual amount of the bribe is usually trivial compared with the cost of the bridge, and doesn't figure in the calculation - it's the increased cost that causes the problem.

With other kinds of bribes there are bigger problems. Let's say the bridge builder uses substandard concrete and bribes the quality inspector not to notice. Now you have a faulty bridge and the cost of replacing it when it collapses (plus some dead people if it collapses at the wrong time). Or your police official is bribed to not arrest a crime lord. Crime usually costs someone money, so society is again worse off by quite a lot.

Comment: @DJC - This is so gonna get downvoted for lack of links...

Comment: That's fine if it happens. It seemed to me like the questioner was looking for an explanation rather than a scientific analysis.

Comment: @DVK: Then we should kick the downvoters' butts. :) This is an obvious issue. It's like asking if 5-3 really is less than 5. :-)

Comment: @Lennart - I have seen many "5-3<5" answers with no references get downvoted, both mine and others. Sklivvz's template is very explicit about "no original research" :(

Comment: I just upvoted.  References?  Stop this nonsense when it's absolutely not needed.

Comment: @DVK: no it should be downvoted because it's pointless. The question to be answered is: "Is the damage to society proven by facts?" and not "Can you imagine a way in which bribery could damage society?"

Comment: @jae: If you disagree with our current policy, feel free to bring this up on meta.

Answer (score 1):

This type of "questions" can mostly be answered looking at the **worst-case scenario**. Thats what actually surprises me. After nuclear disaster in **Japan** and state bankrupt of **Greece** one should already know before finishing the formulation of the question, in which contexts bribery can not only damage, but ruin whole societies.

In Japan one may say, it was technological mismanagment, but according to this [source](http://english.aljazeera.net/indepth/features/2011/06/201161664828302638.html)

> Dr Shoji Sawada is a theoretical
>   particle physicist and Professor
>   Emeritus at Nagoya University in
>   Japan. He is concerned about the types
>   of nuclear plants in his country, and
>   the fact that most of them are of US
>   design.
>
> "Most of the reactors in Japan were
>   designed by US companies who did not
>   care for the effects of earthquakes,"
>   Dr Sawada told Al Jazeera. "I think
>   this problem applies to all nuclear
>   power stations across Japan."
>
> Using nuclear power to produce
>   electricity in Japan is a product of
>   the nuclear policy of the US,
>   something Dr Sawada feels is also a
>   large component of the problem.
>
> **"Most of the Japanese scientists at
>   that time, the mid-1950s, considered
>   that the technology of nuclear energy
>   was under development or not
>   established enough, and that it was
>   too early to be put to practical use,"
>   he explained. "The Japan Scientists
>   Council recommended the Japanese
>   government not use this technology
>   yet, but the government accepted to
>   use enriched uranium to fuel nuclear
>   power stations, and was thus subjected
>   to US government policy."**

one has to ask, if japan scientists were just overruled or the wrong scientists/politicians, giving legitimation to nuclear power plants (not optimized towards Japan unique environmental risks), were bribed. Same with security inspectors for local plants...

[Economy of Greece:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Greece)

> The country suffers from high levels
>   of political and economic corruption
>   and low global competitiveness
>   compared to its EU partners.

Comment: While bad things have resulted from bribes, I don't think this answer is helpful because it doesn't show that even better things haven't happened as a result of bribes.  For example, what if bribes led to modern medicine?  I don't think the worst case scenario analysis presented here answers the question asked..."Does bribery have more negative effects on a developing nation than positive effects, if any?"